# Wondering why Static Constructor is not hit in derived class and base class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, c#-4.0, constructor

This is a little sample I was helping myself for understanding constructors working with many scenarios. I am surprised why static constructors in this scene is not being hit at all.

I am well aware about the Static constructors and even have experienced how they work. I know that, first the static constructor in the derived class gets hit and then the one in base class and then any other constructors. But I don't know why in this particular case where I "ENFORCE" base class parameterized constructor to work, is this the reason the static constructors are not getting hit ? This is what I could suspect/understand, however I may be wrong. But I cannot agree with this, if this is going to be the reason.

Here s the code I worked in VS 2010 now:

```
    public class MyBaseClass
    {
        public MyBaseClass(int x)
        {
        }
        static MyBaseClass()
        {
        }
    }

    public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
    {
        public MyDerivedClass(int i)
            : base(5)
        {
        }
        public MyDerivedClass() : base(2)
        {
        }
        static MyDerivedClass()
        {
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            new MyDerivedClass();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do the static constructors actually do?  How do you know they are not being hit?  Have you put in breakpoints?  Or is there logic that should be run that isn't?  It is hard to tell what exactly is going on when all of the methods are empty.

Comment: I can't reproduce, with a `Main()` method on a different class OR as you have posted. Putting breakpoints on the static constructors as well as the `new` call will break on all of them.

Comment: What might make things confusing is that I *don't* see the static constructors if I continually use "Step into" in VS. I only see that they're executed when I set a breakpoint.

Comment: Why would you _see_ them executed if you are not breaking?

Comment: @cadrell0: Buddy, I started the application with "F11" which would take you from the very beginning of the program execution :) "And", I have put the break point in the Main function itself :) I did analyzed it properly before posting here, anyway thank you, lets investigate further if I am not wrong.

Comment: @Oded If I choose "Step into", and execution continues in the static constructor, I expect to step through the static constructor.

Comment: @Oded: I am very sorry, I am afraid that I didn't understood what you have said in your first comment. I am sort of new :(

Comment: @hvd - Which of the two static constructors? I see `MyDerivedClass()` followed by `MyBaseClass()` being called.

Comment: @Divine The same thing as me: if you set a breakpoint on the opening brace of the static constructors, you'll see they do in fact get called.

Comment: Divine - I am saying that I can see both of the static constructors being hit, when I put a breakpoint on the `{` of each constructor. I also tested with moving the `Main` method to a different class.

Comment: @Oded Yes, but you've set a breakpoint. Do you also see that if you choose "Step into"? I don't, on my system "Step into" executes the static constructors and breaks after the static constructors have finished and the next function starts.

Comment: @hvd: Absolutely you are right, I see that. But how :S This is not fair that without putting breakpoint we can't see the execution. But I remember " The same static constructors got hit in my another example of a question I posted here wrt Static COnstructors hierarchy of execution in this forum, you can see in my profile questions I asked here. " I am surprised what would be the reason behind this difference in behavior

Comment: @Oded: Oh I see, I got it, well yeah thats getting hit when we put breakpoint. And its true that first derived class static gets hit and then the base class and I am aware that we dont have control over which one should get hit first when its static unlike normal instance constructors.

Comment: @hvd - Sorry, I now get what you mean. No, `step into` doesn't work with static constructors. Apparently this is a known issue and there is a MS connect thread requesting the option.

Comment: @Oded: I also observe that, once this static cons in derived is hit, then the control goes to instance constructor in derived through Main and not to static in base. I am confused why is this. I should see, static of derived, then static of base then it should go to Main. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: @Divine - I see a different order. The static cons in derived fires, then the call in `Main` executes. At this point the static cons in base fires, then the instance constructor in derived (which is chained to the base class, which is the last one to be called).

Comment: @Oded: Well I see that, 1. Static in Derived gets executed 2. Goes to Main then hits the derived class parameterless constructor 3. Goes to Static in Base and executes 4. Then Instance in Base gets executed 5. Then last the instance constructor in derived class gets executed. Is that the same with you ?

Comment: @Divine - Yes. This is what I would expect to happen too.

Comment: @Oded: Oh ok thank you for confirming me the same, I am satisfied. But yes just wondering on this MS debugging bug that static is not hit without breakpoint. This leads to great confusions of the concept like this :) Anyway thank you so much and its my earnest request for folks like you to get this noticed to MS and bug fix can happen and lead to better product/sofwatre :) Cheers thank you again.

Comment: @Divine - It is a known issue, probably there to make it easier to implement the debugger. MS have has this raised before, but who know if and when that will change.

Comment: @Oded: Oh ok :) Hope it gets resolved soon :) I am new to learning concepts in programming and so gets a bit nervous/excited when I work out examples and see things not happening the way it should, although its aknown bug. I also pointed out one more thing with reference to local variables scope which is also a kind of unexpected behavior/bug I see, I have asked this question and someone answered that, this is "Skeptical scope" and not the good idea too from MS... Anyway thank you so much for taking your time to answer, I appreciate it, hope to discuss more with you folks :) cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why series0ne's answer is -ve marked. It's a detailed explanation of how constructors work, with examples.

However, one thing I like to point out is that static constructors of base and derived will be called in addition to default/specific constructors by simply doing 'new B()' as the only statement. You don't need to declare a variable of type A (or B for that matter) and assign to it to ensure static constructor of base is invoked. (Contradicting comment - series0ne Aug 17 '12 at 14:09)

Following is the an example (I wrote to verify) and its outcome:

```
class A
{
    static A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static A.");
    }

    public A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Non-Static A.");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    static B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static B.");
    }

    public B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Non-Static B.");
    }
}

void Main()
{
    new B();
}

Static B.
Static A.
Non-Static A.
Non-Static B.
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT - Inconsistent and incomplete testing led to an incorrect answer on my part, and with the interest of clear, concise and CORRECT answers, this post has been entirely updated.**

**The difference between static and non-static constructors:**

A static constructor is called automatically before the first use of an object. It's purpose is to set up any static fields/properties/objects(etc.) of itself before any instantiation of itself occurs. Therefore if I define class A to have a static constructor, and create an instance of A, the static constructor will execute before A is instantiated.

Let's say for example that I construct two instances of A, I only see the static constructor for A once...why!? Because static construction only needs to occur once for a particular object type. Beyond that, there is no point in performing static constructions because its already been done!

**Consider the following code for this exercise:**

```
    public class A
    {
        static A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from static A");
        }

        public A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from non-static A");
        }
    }

    public class B : A
    {
        static B()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from static B");
        }

        public B() : base() //explicit so you know B() will call A()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from non-static B");
        }
    }
```

**Consider the following instantiation of A and it's results:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A instance_1 = new A();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

**Results:** *Hello from static A, Hello from non-static A*

Since A is instantiated once in this instance, static A is called, then non-static A

**Consider the following instantiation of A (x2) and it's results:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A instance_1 = new A();
        A instance_2 = new A();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

**Results:** *Hello from static A, Hello from non-static A, Hello from non-static A*

As A is instantiated twice, static A is called once (as static A is a one-time operation) and non-static A is called twice to create two instances of A

**Consider the following instantiation of B assigned to from A and it's results:**

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A instance_1 = new B();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

**Results:** *Hello from static B, Hello from static A, Hello from non-static A, Hello from non-static B*

Now both A and B are being statically constructed (first time only) because B is a descendant of A. This is evident as well in that non-static B calls non-static A. as A is the ancestor or B

**Finally consider this example...**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A instance_1 = new B();
        B instance_2 = new B();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

**Results:** *Hello from static B, Hello from static A, Hello from non-static A, Hello from non-static B, Hello from non-static A, Hello from non-static B*

Again, A and B are statically constructed (one time only) but non-static A and non-static B repeat as their are now two instances of B, therefore the non-static construction occurs for every new instance of the object

It might be worth also taking note that it appears that static construction and non-static construction calls in inheritance work the opposite way round to each other. I.E. in the last example, static B is called before static A, however non-static A is called before non-static B!

Comment: Hi thank you for sharing this inputs, but can I say B inst2 = new B() will also have to call static A if A inst1 = new B() wasn't there ? As static constructors has to be called once. I may be wrong. But wondering.

Comment: No...if A is never declared or assigned to, static A() will never be called.

Comment: B instance = new B() will call default ctor A, then default ctor B

Comment: Consider using composition pattern if you need B to call static A...you can read my article on advanced composition pattern here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14542/multiple-inheritance-and-composition-with-java-and-c-updated

Comment: Hi Matthew: Well I get the result as Hello From static ctor A 
        Hello From default ctor A 
        Hello From B 
When I just have B inst2 = new B();

Comment: @MatthewLayton I am afraid that's not right. The static ctor of A will be called when you do B inst2 = new B(). so the order would be "static ctor A", "default ctor A" and "default ctor B". That's the way constructors work in C#. Statics always get called once before the instance ctors.

Comment: @Amn...if that is the case then why are my results as such? it does not appear that B inst = new B() called static A() ?

Comment: @MatthewLayton: I am worried, I got that above posted result in my last comment. And I did analyzed this well to my knowledge that it is hitting Static A and it should. We should investigate more in your case.

Comment: @Divine, I will test again and ILSpy it...that may shed some light.

Comment: @MatthewLayton: Sure thank you for your time and thoughts on sharing knowledge

Comment: @Divine..OK I have worked it out... my first call was A inst = new B(); this calls static ctor A because static ctor A has not yet been called. then I do this...B inst2 = new B(), this appears not to call static ctor A becuase its already been done by the first instantiation. if you swap A inst1 = new B() with B inst2 = new B(), B will then call static ctor A() because it has not yet been done....Now I feel silly due to lack of testing! :-/

Comment: to clarify, it appears that static ctor's are only called upon the declaring objects first use, beyond that it will not be called again.

Comment: @MatthewLayton: You are absolutely right. That's alright buddy, no worries at all, everybody learns only through experience. Now you learnt the triggering point ;) Keep learning and sharing knowledge for the needy, cheers :)

Comment: @MatthewLayton: Yes, static constructor has to be called once at the beginning. And it will never be called again. And if you get time, also see one of my question on static constructors execution hierarchy, that's a good discussion as well. Cheers... :)